# Swift: Is it possible to fully manipulate webpage elements such as TextField and Button?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, swift3

Is it possible in Swift to have a **WebView** open a webpage, automatically fill in some of the webpage's **TextFields** with data from my App, and press certain webpage **Buttons**. Then extract some **String** data from the webpage.

Is this possible solely in Swift or will I need to learn other languages as well?

Comment: what about javaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is using [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize), a **Ruby** library that fits exactly with your problem.

I've used it and works perfectly.

Comment: after quick research, it seems so. Would you mind adding a very simplistic method of how to implement a Ruby Library into a Swift app. This would be greatly appreciated.  I have limited programming education. Do I save the Ruby Library as a file in my App and then import it into the file that I need and from there i can now call "Ruby Mechanize" functions?. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue solely through Swift. I have yet to learn Ruby or libraries so I'd assume this is not the most efficient method but I'd still like to share.

It requires Inspecting Elements in the webpage to find Id's. i.e. `ButtonName`, `TextFieldName`

Button Press: `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('ButtonName').click()")`

Textfield Fill: `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('TextFieldName').value = '\(YourTextString)\'")`